# Find $f^{(302)}(0)$ where $f(z)=\sin(z^{100}+z^{101})$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

Find $$f^{(302)}(0)$$ where $$f(z)=\sin(z^{100}+z^{101})~~~and~~~z\in \mathbb{C}$$

Can anyone  help me with this problem I really don't where to start.

please at least any idea to where to start

Comment: Do you mean $f^{(302)}(0)$?

Comment: @Teddy38..yes thats right

Comment: Hint: $$f(z)=z^{100}+z^{101}+\tfrac16(z^{100}+z^{101})^3+O(z^n)$$ for some large $n$ I will let you discover.

Comment: @Did..if you expension sinx then it should be $\sin x=x-x^3/3!+---$

Comment: @suresh Typo, indeed. You got the idea...

Comment: Why this post is on holds?

Comment: @GuyFsone Because it is a typical do-my-homework-for-me-asap-thx question. Obviously. Why do you ask?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With  $\phi(z)= z^{100}(1+z)$ we have $$f(z) = \sin(\phi(z))= \phi(z)-  \phi(z)^3/6 +o( \phi(z)^3)$$

$$f(z) = \sin(\phi(z))= z^{100}(1+z)- \frac{z^{300}(1+z)^3}{6}+o( \phi(z)^3)\\=z^{100}(1+z)- \frac{z^{300}(1+3z+\color{red}{3z^2}+z^3)}{6}+o( \phi(z)^3)\\= z^{100}(1+z))-\frac{1}{6}z^{300}-\frac{1}{2}z^{301}-\frac{1}{2}z^{302}+ o(z^{303})$$
Hence

$$\frac{f^{(302)}(0)}{302!} = -\frac{1}{2}\implies 
\color{blue}{f^{(302) }=-\frac{302!}{2}}$$

Comment: ...i think $\sin x=x-x^3/6+..$

Comment: why did some down vote this?